# Ubuntu | Ruby - Can't Remove Ruby 1.9.2 from system

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I'm new to ubuntu, and might have had a couple of
false starts updating ruby / rails. I'm trying
to start clean by removing all versions of every
thing ruby from my system

I think I've installed everything through either
Synaptic, or aptitude purge, but I can still do the
following:

```
jwally@jwally-laptop:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]

jwally@jwally-laptop:~$ gem -v
1.3.7

jwally@jwally-laptop:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"
```

but when I type "dpkg -l | grep ruby, 
I only get the following:

```
rc  ruby1.8-elisp                        1.8.7.249-2                                     ruby-mode for Emacsen
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which package `ruby` is owned by run:

```
dpkg -S `which ruby`
```

If it can't find the package, then Ruby was installed outside of the Ubuntu package manager.  You'll have to remove it manually.

I'll once again recommend this blog post for instructions on the best way to install Ruby on Ubuntu: [Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you).

Comment: on a scale of 0-stupid, how bad of an idea is it if I were to just delete the ruby-1.9.2-p0 directory?

Comment: Probably not a terrible idea if you're going to use `rvm` in the future.

This command may be helpful in your search to remove files: `sudo updatedb` followed by `locate ruby | less`

Comment: jwally@jwally-laptop:~$ dpkg -S `which ruby`
    dpkg: /usr/local/bin/ruby not found.

Comment: Yah, you'll have to remove the files manually.  Definitely switch to `rvm` as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You may have installed an instance of Ruby without using Ubuntu's package system.  Try:

```
which ruby
```

If this yields something other than `/usr/bin/ruby` (such as `/usr/local/bin/ruby`), then this is the case.  Ubuntu can't uninstall locally installed stuff.  You need to do that manually.

Comment: which ruby yields the following: /usr/local/bin/ruby

Comment: however, file search returns: Ruby1.9.2-p0 in directory of home/jwally

Comment: If the latter directory is the source directory, you could try cd'ing there and doing a “make uninstall”.  I don't know whether the Ruby distribution supports that, however.

Comment: make uninstall gives: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.

Comment: so if I want it gone, can I just delete the directory?

Comment: Well...  Deleting the source directory won't make the installed instance go away.  You'll need to remove Ruby from /usr/local.  Unfortunately, there is no simple way of doing that that I know of (short of deleting /usr/local, which, of course, deletes all other software installed there as well).